# What open cover should i consider in order to show $(X,d)$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X= \mathbb R$,let

$d(x,y)=\frac{\left|x-y\right|}{1+\vert  x-y \vert} \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Show that $(X,d)$ is not compact.

What is the form of open sets of $(X,d)$?

Comment: It can be shown that the metric listed is equivalent to the standard in the sense that they induce the same topology.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an open cover, consider $\{B(0, 1- \frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \}$. Every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has distance $d(0, x) < 1$, so is covered by one of these open balls. ANd as $n$ gets larger $d(0,n) \rightarrow 1$, so we cannot have a finite subcover, as the ball with the largest radius will not contain some $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Similarly, we can consider the sequence $x_n = n$ and show it has no convergent subsequence (despite it even being Cauchy)

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ were compact, the map $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto d(x,0)$ would have a compact image.  Does it?

Comment: :$d(x,o)=\frac{x}{1+\vert  x \vert} $ is continous on $\mathbb R$.Also,the continuous image of a  compact metric space is compact.Hence,f(X) is compact.From this how can we conclude that (X,d) is not compact?

Comment: @PKStyles Contrapositively, if $f(X)$ is not compact, $X$ is not compact.  What is $f(X)$?

Comment: @Metthew Leingang:Since d(x,0) is a homeomorphism.So X is also compact.Which is  a contrary conclusion to the desired result.

Comment: @PKStyles no, $d(x,0)$ is not a homeomorphism; it's not bijective.  And you seem to believe that $f(X)$ is compact.  Are you sure?